# How to understand the concept behind the equation $\boldsymbol{Ax}=\boldsymbol{b}$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

As is know to all, the equation $\boldsymbol{Ax}=\boldsymbol{b}$ can be understand as to find the linear combination coefficient of the column vector of the matrix $A$. At the same time, it can also be explained as to find vector space which is orthogonal to all the row vectors. So I think there must be some connections between this two problems. Maybe we can call them dual problems, Can anyone explain the connections between the two explanations for me?

Comment: The thing about finding the vector space being orthogonal to the rows - doesn't that only work for the equation $Ax=0$, where the right-hand-side is 0?

Comment: @user2875124 yes, only b=0, it works.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the equation $Ax=b$ goes, the left-hand-side can the thought of in different ways.

One way is that if $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ are the columns of $A$, and $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, then

$Ax = a_1x_1+\cdots+a_nx_n,$

which is a linear combination of the columns of $A$. Thus to solve the equation, you need to find the values of $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ such that this linear combination is equal to $b$.

But the left-hand-side $Ax$ can also be thought of in the following way, which is the usual "row times column" way of thinking about matrix products. If the rows of $A$ are $c_1,\ldots,c_n$, then $Ax$ is the vector whose $i$'th entry is the dot product $c_i\cdot x$. In the special case of the equation $Ax=0$, you get that $c_i\cdot x=0$ for all $i$, and thus that $x$ is orthogonal to all row vectors of $A$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want to know the connections between the two concept.